# Implement Equals for DropDownListFor with a non-primitive object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have an object `Modem` with the property `Protocol` which is bound to a `DropDownListFor`. The value of Modem in the DropDownList isn't selected.

```
public class Modem {

   public Protocol Protocol { get; set; }

}

public class Protocol {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller code

```
var modem = new Modem{ Protocol = new Protocol { Name = "UDP", Value = "The udp protocol" } };
var protocols = new List<Protocol>{ new Protocol { Name = "TCP", Value = "The tcp protocol" }, new Protocol { Name = "UDP", Value = "The udp protocol" } };
ViewBag.Protocols = protocols.Select(p => new SelectListItem{ Value = p.Name, Text = p.Value });

return View(modem);
```

My View code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modem => modem.Protocol, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Protocols)
```

If I manually set the selected protocol that doesn't work.  So can I implement `Equals` like this (already tried doing this with `Protocol`, but it didn't work...)

```
public bool Equals(object obj){
    if(obj == null){
        return false;
    }
    var protocol = obj as Protocol;
    return protocol != null && protocol.Name == Name;
}
```

**Update :**
I tried using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modem => modem.Protocol, new SelectList(ViewBag.Protocols, "Name", "Value", Model.Protocol))
```

But didn't work too :(.

**Update 2 :**
Using reflector, I have found this line :

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(from value in enumerable.Cast<object>() select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

So DropDownListFor uses the ToString method to do the set of the default value.
With this ToString method, I could do what I wanted :

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Name;
}
```

---

Comment: You don't need to implement `Equals` at all - just perform the reverse mapping from `SelectListItem.Value` back to your `Protocol` class in your POST handling action.

Comment: I did not understand.
When the form is displayed, I would like that the DropDownList has the Model.Protocol has default value.